# How do I iterate through an array of hashes in puppet 3.8?

Tags: loops, iteration, puppet

I am trying to set up a simple puppet class to loop through an array of hashes, each of which contain configuration for a yum repository. I am using Puppet version 3.8.2 which means that using a .each function is not possible.

Currently my puppet code looks like this:

```
class ::yum_repos {

      $repos = [
                  {
                    'name'  => 'test_repo1',
                    'base_url' => 'example1.com',
                    'ensure'  => 'present',
                    'gpgcheck' => 'true',
                  },
                  {
                    'name'  => 'test_repo2',
                    'base_url' => 'example2.com',
                    'ensure'  => 'present',
                    'gpgcheck' => 'true',
                  },
               ]

      define add_repo {
        yumrepo { $name:
          ensure   => $ensure,
          name     => $name,
          baseurl  => $base_url,
          gpgcheck => $gpgcheck,
          enabled  => 'true',
        }
      }
      add_repo { $repos: }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this is throwing the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Could not intern from text/pson: Could not intern from data: Could not find relationship source "::yum_repos::Add_repo[nametest_repo2ensurepresentgpgchecktruebase_urlexample2.com]"
```

Is anybody able to explain the correct method of doing this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: It is possible to use .each in 3.8.2 with the future parser. Also, if you are determined to use an ancient version of Puppet, then for the sake of security and stability you should probably update to the latest patch version at least. If you want to not use the future parser, then what you are trying to achieve is documented regarding usage here: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/function.html#createresources. Let us know what route you want.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll have a go at using the documentation you have provided regarding the use of create_resources. If it works, then pop it down as the answer and I'll mark it as solved. I'll get back to you!

Comment: Your reference to the documentation was exactly the answer I needed, thanks for your help! If you submit it as an answer I can mark the issue as solved via your fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over resource declarations (or larger blocks of code) in Puppet < 4 without the future parser, we need to make use of hashes, a defined resource type (if not iterating over an intrinsic type), and the `create_resources` function. The usage is documented [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/function.html#createresources).

For your specific case, the code would look like:

```
# hash of resources
$repos = {
  'test_repo1' => { 'base_url' => 'example1.com',
                    'ensure'   => present,
                    'gpgcheck' => true,
  },
  'test_repo2' => { 'base_url' => 'example2.com',
                    'ensure'   => present,
                    'gpgcheck' => true,
  },
}

# iterate over resource declarations
create_resources(yumrepo, $repos)
```

If you wanted to iterate over a larger block of resources, then using your defined resource type as an example, we would modify the above accordingly:

```
# defined resource type encapsulating code to iterate over
define add_repo($ensure, $base_url, $gpgcheck) {
  yumrepo { $title:
    ensure   => $ensure,
    baseurl  => $base_url,
    gpgcheck => $gpgcheck,
    enabled  => true,
  }
}

# iterate over resource declarations
create_resources(add_repo, $repos)
```